# How can I deploy a contract with a proxy that inherits another contract with a constructor?

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, openzeppelin, chainlink

So I'm currently trying to deploy a contract using TransparentUpgradeableProxy. My contract inherits chainlink's VRFConsumerBaseV2 which has a constructor. That constructor is used to set an immutable variable to ensure only the VRF contract is able to call my randomness function.

My question is, is there any way to deploy it without rewriting VRFConsumerBaseV2 and adding an initializer function?

Answer (score 1):

Try to encode VRFConsumerBaseV2 constructor argument to bytecode and pass it in the `_data` argument in TransparentUpgradeableProxy.

```
contract TransparentUpgradeableProxy is ERC1967Proxy {
/**
 * @dev Initializes an upgradeable proxy managed by `_admin`, backed by the implementation at `_logic`, and
 * optionally initialized with `_data` as explained in {ERC1967Proxy-constructor}.
 */
constructor(address _logic, address admin_, bytes memory _data) payable ERC1967Proxy(_logic, _data) {
    _changeAdmin(admin_);
}
```

Comment: That data field will be used to call a function after the new implementation is set, it won't setup the constructor

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think you can't go around that inherited constructor, and your only way is to refactored the inherited contracts to remove the nested constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but if and only if the sole logic within the constructor is to initialize immutable variables: as immutable variables are in-lined during deployment, the runtime bytecode contains these value as hardcoded/constant, you therefore don't (and can't) initialize them later on (and your proxy contract will "see" them during its delegatecalls).

Any other logic (or non-immutable variable assignment) from the constructor is, obviously, a different scenario.

In your case, you'd deploy the implementation (with the correct value for your immutable variable) then just use it in your proxy.